# calculate age considering the leap year

Tags: android

the method getDaysRemainingForNextBirthDay() does not work for leap year ie.; instead of 12 days remaining for year 1988 , it shows 377 days...How to alter the code to make it work for that ....

```
public long getDaysRemainingForNextBirthDay(){

          String startDate=year+"/"+month+"/"+day;        
          SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
          Date date=null;
          try{
              date=sdf.parse(startDate);
          }
          catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
          Calendar BDay=Calendar.getInstance();
          BDay.setTime(date);
          Calendar today=Calendar.getInstance();
          int BMonth=BDay.get(Calendar.MONTH);
          int CMonth=today.get(Calendar.MONTH);
          BDay.set(Calendar.YEAR,today.get(Calendar.YEAR));
          if (BMonth<=CMonth) {
            BDay.set(Calendar.YEAR,today.get(Calendar.YEAR)+1);
        }
          long millis=(BDay.getTimeInMillis())-(today.getTimeInMillis());
          long remainingDays=millis/(86400000);
          return (remainingDays+1);
      }
```

Comment: sorry it is Calendar.MONTH

Comment: Ok, but now I don't believe that this is your real code.

Comment: I think this check: `if (BMonth<=CMonth)` is wrong, cause the day might still be later even if it's the same month.

Comment: I would *strongly* advise you to use Joda Time for this. It will make your life much, much simpler.

Comment: public String getDaysRemainingForNextBirthDay(){
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    int currentYear=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    DateTime birthDate=new DateTime(currentYear,Integer.parseInt(m),Integer.parseInt(d),0, 0);

    DateTime currentDate=DateTime.now();
    Period datePeriod=new Period(currentDate,birthDate,PeriodType.days());
    PeriodFormatter periodFormatter=new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
    .appendDays().appendSuffix("day").toFormatter();
    
    
    return periodFormatter.print(datePeriod);
   }    returns me 10days , I need only the number i.e.; 10